# Why does Rakudo dd return Nil for a typed and assigned scalar?

Tags: raku, rakudo

The below is a REPL session using Rakudo.

```
> my Int $x = 1
1
> dd $x
Int $x = 1
Nil
```

Why is there a `Nil` on the second line of the output of `dd`?

Comment: Btw, are you using [the REPL in Comma](https://commaide.com/download)?

Comment: No - just the Rakudo Perl 6 app / command line on Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
> sub mydd( $foo ) { dd $foo; "hello" }
&mydd
> mydd $x
1
hello
```

The Nil is the return value of `dd`, or lack thereof to be precise.

Answer (score 7):

It's not "the output of `dd`" but rather output of the REPL based on the value returned by `dd`.

In more detail...

- The **R** in **REPL** reads the line you enter (`dd ...`).
- The **E** evaluates the line. It's `dd`, so it prints a line ending in a newline.
- The **P** prints another line, also ending in a newline. If the evaluation in the prior step did not produce output on STDOUT, then the line this step produces includes the value returned by that evaluation.
- (The **L** then loops around waiting for the next line of input.)

The first line you see after pressing Enter is output generated by `dd`.

The second line you see is output generated by the REPL.

By default, the content of the second line is the REPL's `.gist` of the value returned by the `dd`. [The value `dd` returns](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/f0594084e88e3d36bdcbc220989c7c823233876b/src/core.c/Any.pm6#L625) is (always) `Nil`. So that's what you see.

(Liz has added a new environment variable since this SO was posted that lets users tell Rakudo what method to call; `.gist` is now merely the default.)

Answer (score 7):

The REPL in Raku checks whether the code executed did any output to `STDOUT`.  This is done with the assumption that if your code outputs something, that you would be interested in *that*, not the return value of the expression you just executed.  So that is why:

```
> say 42
42
```

will only show `42` and **not** also show the return value of `say` (which happens to be `True` btw).  It does **not** check `STDERR`.  Check this with `note`:

```
> note 42
42
True
```

`note` is the same as `say`, but puts its output on `STDERR` instead of `STDOUT`.  And the same applies to `dd`.  So that's why you also get this with `dd`:

```
> dd 42
42
Nil
```

Except that the implementation of `dd` is returning `Nil` because it is intended as a debugging aid that should interfere as little as possible with its environment.